# YouTube embeds slowing down page

Tags: iframe, youtube, pagespeed

I have a page with a bunch of thumbnail images that when clicked open embedded youtube videos in modals.

Here is the html:

```
<li>

                    <div class="videoLd">

                        <a class="video-link" title="Video Title" href="#video" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="youtubeid">

                            <img class="responsive-imamge" src="//www.mysite.com/video.jpg" alt="" >

                        </a>


                            <h4>Video Title</h4>


                        <p>Video Description</p>


                        <div id="video" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                <img src="www.mysite.com/close-modal.png" alt=" ">
                            </button>

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="video-wrapper">
                                    <!-- on click the iframe will append here -->                                       
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>


                </li>
```

I'm displaying a list of 5 video thumbnails this way. This has really slowed down my page load time. Before adding the videos the page loaded 61% faster than the avg on my site. Now it's 21% slower.

Is there a way to optimize these videos so they only load when the video thumbnail is clicked?

**EDIT**

Thought I'd update this and share what I'm actually using now. Instead of using the lazyYT plugin I created a simple on click function that appends the iframe to a container div. The link to the video has a data-id attribute that contains the youTube video id.

```
$('.video-link').on('click', function () {
    var youTubeID = $(this).data('id');
    var code="<iframe width='1280' height='720' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/" + youTubeID + "?rel=0&autoplay=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen=''></iframe>";
    $(this).parent().find('.video-wrapper').append(code);
});
```

Comment: Check this link for a solution. It worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72948422/5840973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about lazy loading the Youtube videos instead?

I haven't used it myself, but this [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/tylerpearson/lazyYT) will lazy load Youtube videos. Here is [another plugin](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt/) that will lazy load, but unfortunately it seems that both of them require jQuery which isn't ideal unless your site is already using it.

There is also [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15070795) on SO that covers this question and might give you more insight.

Comment: thanks for the response, lazy load is exactly what I'm looking for.